# osgi-jax-rs-connector is not in use anymore in AEM6.5

Tags: aem, aem-6

I am trying to expose Restful Services in AEM. I am using `jersey-all-2.22.2,publisher-5.3.1,provider-security-2.2` API.

I am getting "HTTP ERROR 503 Jersey is not ready yet!"
[image]

[image]

But looks like `osgi-jax-rs-connector` part of `jersey` is not in use anymore. https://github.com/hstaudacher/osgi-jax-rs-connector

What is the alternative API which can be used instead of `osgi-jax-rs-connector` in AEM6.5

Thanks,
Gana

Comment: Please replace the images in your question.  Here is why: https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/1847378

Comment: Did you make any progress?